# Keyboard Type Decimal Pad - Decimal point background is not in full rectangle - iOS8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

If you selected Keyboard Type Decimal Pad then by running the app, Decimal point background is not in full rectangle in iOS8. Its strange. Any body have any solution of it?
My client reported it to make the rectangle's background same as "Back" button rectangle background.

Many Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Under iOS8 the keyboard is more transparent. What do you have under the keyboard?

Comment: @LeoNatan Its the screenshot of simulator's keyboard. I have just created new sample application and add text filed. Background view is totally white. Not any thing under keyboard.

Comment: Could be an OS bug/design. Try the same project with iOS8.1 SDK.